# GetSellerList Returning My Own Items With Another Userid Specified

Tags: php, soap, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I'm seeing some unusual activity with the Trading API using the `GetSellerList` action. Making any call while I'm specifying ANY value results in me returning only my eBay items. I'm looking at pulling another users sellerslist, not my own. I've tried multiple API versions, but my script is using 871.

```php
<?php
 
function print_d($array){    echo "<pre>\n";    print_r($array);    echo "</pre>\n";}
 
$mytoken = "*************mytoken ****************";
$devId = "**************devId ***************";
$appId = "*************appId ***************";
$certId = "**************certId **************";
 
$wsdl_url = 'http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/ebaySvc.wsdl';
 
$apiCall = "GetSellerList";
 
$credentials = array('AppId' => $appId, 'DevID' => $devId, 'AuthCert' => $certId);
 
$client = new SOAPClient($wsdl_url, array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 0, 'location' => "https://api.ebay.com/wsapi?callname=$apiCall&appid=$appId&siteid=0&version=871&Routing=new"));
 
$eBayAuth = array('eBayAuthToken' => new SoapVar($mytoken, XSD_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents'),
                    'Credentials' => new SoapVar ($credentials, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents'));  
                    
$header_body = new SoapVar($eBayAuth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);    
 
$header = array(new SOAPHeader('urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents', 'RequesterCredentials', $header_body));                
 
//set the API call parameters
 
$params = array('UserID'=>'**userid**','DetailLevel'=>'ReturnAll','GranularityLevel'=>'Coarse','WarningLevel'=>'High','IncludeWatchCount'=>'true','Pagination'=>array('EntriesPerPage'=>20,'PageNumber'=>1),'Version' => 871, 'StartTimeFrom'=>'2019-07-01T01:01:02.768Z' ,'StartTimeTo'=>'2019-08-22T01:01:02.768Z');  
 
$request = $client->__soapCall($apiCall, array($params), NULL, $header);  //make the actual API call
 
print_d($request);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

GetSellerList from Ebay's API can only be used for your own account, as specified in their official documentation:

> Use this call to retrieve items listed by the authenticated user, including item data.

https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetSellerList.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35317474)